# My name shows up for every call to my gf's iPhone?

Tags: iphone

android guy here.  Recently my gf's iPhone has been showing my name for any contact that calls here, even if they're in her contact book.  She's not very tech savvy and I'm not close to her phone to check it out.

I don't even know where to begin googling this.  It's gotten annoying at this point.  Has anybody experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you: https://communityforums.rogers.com/t5/Account-Support/Caller-ID-Name-Display-Showing-Wrong-Name/td-p/396434

I have never experienced this but I could relate to it!

Comment: Not the same.  It’s not obvious, but if you read carefully, OP’s name appears when _anyone_ calls the GF.  The Roger’s issue is that every time that guy called, ONE name other than his was displayed.